# False from dataframe evaluation in R

Tags: r, if-statement

Here is my example

```
my_df <- data.frame(col_1 = c(1,2,4), col_2 = c('A', 'B', 'C'))
```

I would like to create if statement based on the following expression

```
my_df[my_df$col_1==5,'col_2']
```

This value currently returns:

```
factor(0)
Levels: A B C
```

How do I compare it

```
my_df[my_df$col_1==5,'col_2'] == 0?
is.na(my_df[my_df$col_1==5,'col_2']) ?
```

nothing works

This works, but a bit clumsy

```
NROW(my_df[my_df$col_1==5,'col_2'])==0
```

Comment: `any(my_df$col_1 == 5)` maybe?

Comment: if only 1 column then you can try `length((my_df[my_df$col_1==5,'col_2']))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if all elements of col_1 are equal to 5, then 
     `if(all(my_df$col_1)==5)`
To check if any of the elements of col_2 are equal to 5:
     `if(any(my_df$col_1)==5)`